# NGRX/router select parent route data

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-entity, ngrx-store-4.0

I want to get the route data for the parent route from the current route. Is it possible? The documentation here https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/selectors shows only how to get the route data from the current route.

Comment: Yes you can. I did it like in this tutorial and i am able to select all params of the route https://dev.to/salimchemes/how-to-implement-ngrx-router-store-4552

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the `paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'` option from the Angular Router.

https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/til-paramsinheritancestrategy-to-always-have-access-to-parent-route-info